# Python build error with Stable Diffusion repository: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement triton==2.0.0`

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to run the Python build for the Stable Diffusion SDXL project: https://github.com/Stability-AI/generative-models

I'm mostly following the simple instructions provided on the github page. The project page says it supports Python 3.8 and Python 3.10. I tried Python 3.10, got an error that some dependency required `Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.10`, so I tried Python 3.8, and I get a different error, which I show below:

```bash
git clone git@github.com:Stability-AI/generative-models.git
cd generative-models

rm -rf .pt2
/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3.8 -m venv .pt2
source .pt2/bin/activate

pip3 install -r requirements/pt2.txt
```

I'm snipping out some of the logs and including the error and a few lines before the error. I'm not sure what is wrong and what can I do to get this working?

```
<snip>
Collecting torchmetrics>=1.0.1
  Using cached torchmetrics-1.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (764 kB)
Collecting torchvision>=0.15.2
  Using cached torchvision-0.15.2-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (1.4 MB)
Collecting tqdm>=4.65.0
  Using cached tqdm-4.66.1-py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
Collecting transformers==4.19.1
  Using cached transformers-4.19.1-py3-none-any.whl (4.2 MB)
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 0.55.2 Requires-Python <3.5; 1.11.0 Requires-Python <3.13,>=3.9; 1.11.0rc1 Requires-Python <3.13,>=3.9; 1.11.0rc2 Requires-Python <3.13,>=3.9; 1.11.1 Requires-Python <3.13,>=3.9; 1.11.2 Requires-Python <3.13,>=3.9; 1.25.0 Requires-Python >=3.9; 1.25.0rc1 Requires-Python >=3.9; 1.25.1 Requires-Python >=3.9; 1.25.2 Requires-Python >=3.9; 1.26.0 Requires-Python <3.13,>=3.9; 1.26.0b1 Requires-Python <3.13,>=3.9; 1.26.0rc1 Requires-Python <3.13,>=3.9; 2.1.0 Requires-Python >=3.9; 2.1.0rc0 Requires-Python >=3.9; 2.1.1 Requires-Python >=3.9; 3.8.0 Requires-Python >=3.9; 3.8.0rc1 Requires-Python >=3.9
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement triton==2.0.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for triton==2.0.0
```

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: @ВиталийАбрамов Mac OS X 13.6 and I can update to Mac OS X 14.x but I presume that doesn't matter. I'm running an Apple Silicon M1 Mac if that matters. I just redownloaded everything and retried the steps above with both Python 3.8.18 and 3.9.18 and get the same error described above.

Comment: I've found this doc https://github.com/openai/triton#compatibility 
It says "Linux only" :( so i assume one must install docker vm, run linux inside and install triton there

Comment: I'm not posting this as a solution, given the way it's worded, but if you're on OS X and trying to run Stable Diffusion, this guy's version works *way* easier: https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/wiki/Installation-on-Apple-Silicon

Answer (score 1):

This works on windows. Below versions on which it worked for me :

Python  : 3.10.9

Windows : 10 pro

```
pip install https://huggingface.co/r4ziel/xformers_pre_built/resolve/main/triton-2.0.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
```

refer : https://github.com/openai/triton/issues/1057

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem, it seems that triton doesn't support Windows platform, so you have to switch to Linux. See the [official homepage here](https://github.com/openai/triton#compatibility).